# DuplicateMappingException represented by different logical column names

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I'm using OneToMany mapping for two classes MasavNew and MasavRow  :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ArgoCHFileHdr")
public class MasavNew  {


@OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "msv",cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@ElementCollection(targetClass=MasavRow.class)
private List<MasavRow> rows;

@Id
@Column(name = "[Arg.CH.F.Key]", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
protected Integer argCHFKey;

}


@Entity
@Table(name = "ArgoCHFileRow")
@DynamicUpdate
public class MasavRow extends IModel {


@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,optional=true)
@JoinColumn(name="[Arg.CH.F.Key]")
private MasavNew msv;


@Id
@Column(name = "[Arg.CH.F.Key]", nullable = false)
private int argCHFKey;


@Id
@Column(name = "[Arg.CH.L.MNB]", nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer argCHLMNB;


@Column(name = "[Erp.Clnt]", nullable = true)
private String erpClnt;


}
```

and then in running I receive next Exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException:  Table [ArgoCHFileRow] contains physical column name [`Arg.CH.F.Key`] represented by different logical column names: [`Arg.CH.F.Key`], [Arg.CH.F.Key]
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.bindPhysicalToLogical(Configuration.java:3185)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl$TableColumnNameBinding.addBinding(Configuration.java:3158)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration$MappingsImpl.addColumnBinding(Configuration.java:3202)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.addColumnBinding(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:532)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3Column.linkWithValue(Ejb3Column.java:364)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.linkJoinColumnWithValueOverridingNameIfImplicit(TableBinder.java:523)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.TableBinder.bindFk(TableBinder.java:457)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:117)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processEndOfQueue(Configuration.java:1596)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.processFkSecondPassInOrder(Configuration.java:1519)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1420)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1844)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1928)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBuilder.java:343)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.buildSessionFactory(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:431)
    at org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalSessionFactoryBean.java:416)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1612)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1549)
```

How could I solve the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
@Id
@Column(name = "[Arg.CH.F.Key]", nullable = false)
private int argCHFKey;
```

As you can get the key from your msv object.

Comment: I want to have this coloumn when I work directly with the table

Comment: override your getArgCHFKey() method to return msv.getKey();

Comment: I need to retrieve all rows from ArgoCHFileRow table by argCHFKey key